# Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module while trying to enqueue scripts in wordpress

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, webpack, parceljs

I am trying to enqueue script in my wordpress plugin. But the script includes import statements. That's why I am getting this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here I am using parceljs but the problem is that **parcel.js** recognizes only .js or .html files as entry point. Below is the code in my **package.json** file

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel my-plugin.php",
    "build": "parcel build my-plugin.php"
  },
```

It works fine when I am out of wordpress plugin directory. And if I pass any .html file to parcel scripts it works.

How can I do this? What alternative can I use?